# dlookup slow results

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a problem in access 2010 where my dlookup runs very slow but if I already have the saved query open it runs pretty quickly.  Any Idea has to why this is and how to get around the problem

edit

```
txtPurchase_Price = DLookup("Purchase_Price", "qryPurchaseInfo", "ID = " & check)
```

That is the dlookup

And the sql for the query is

```
SELECT Receiving.Serial,Purchase_Info.Purchase_Price, Purchase_Info.Check_Number,
  Purchase_Info.Purchase_Date, Purchase_Info.ID, Receiving.Source
FROM Purchase_Info INNER JOIN Receiving ON 
  Purchase_Info.ID = Receiving.Purchase_Price_ID;
```

Comment: DLookUp is frequently slow. Have you got suitable indexes?

Comment: Yea I realize that DLookUp is usually slow but when I run the dlookup query on a different table, larger table it runs alot faster.

Comment: Has far has indexes yes I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why you're using a query as the data source (the *Domain* option) for `DLookup`.  That makes sense if your intention is to restrict the set of allowable `Purchase_Info.ID` values to those also present as `Receiving.Purchase_Price_ID` values.

But if that is the case, try a simpler query instead.

```
SELECT
    Purchase_Info.Purchase_Price,
    Purchase_Info.ID
FROM Purchase_Info INNER JOIN Receiving
ON Purchase_Info.ID = Receiving.Purchase_Price_ID;
```

Although, I'm skeptical that query would produce a dramatic speed improvement, I can't understand why it would be slow as long as you have indexes on both `Purchase_Info.ID` and `Receiving.Purchase_Price_ID`.

OTOH, if that wasn't your intention, then you should be able to retrieve `Purchase_Price` directly from your `Purchase_Info` table without needing to join it to the `Receiving` table.  This should be quick with an index on `Purchase_Info.ID`:

```
DLookup("Purchase_Price", "Purchase_Info", "ID = " & check)
```

Finally, I don't know what `check` is.  It could be the name of a control on a form.  But, whatever it is, I would prefer to give it a different name because `check` is a reserved word.  I can never predict when reserved words as object names will cause trouble, so prefer to avoid them completely.

Comment: I will try your suggestions and see if there are any noticeable improvements.  Has far has the check it is the result of a previous DLookup based on a scanned serial number.  I wasn't aware that it was a reserved word.